# CsvHelper, writing dynamic variable names (c#)

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Assume  want to write bank user account details in a following csv file format.

```
AccountId, Name, Jan, Feb, Mar ........... Dec
1, Anne, 1000.00, 400.00, 500.00 .......... 200.00
2, John, 900.00, 400.00, 500.00 .......... 1200.00
3, Brit, 600.00, 400.00, 500.00 .......... 2200.00
```

To represent this above data structure I have following model class:

```
class AccountBalance {
      int ID { get; set; };
      string Name { get; set; };
      List<string> lastTwelveMonths { get; set; };
}
```

My Code is to write csv is:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(stringWriter))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(listOfAccountBalances);
    streamWriter.Write(stringWriter.GetStringBuilder());
    streamWriter.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

But above code will not give exact output when it comes to list of lastTwelveMonths. Could some one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a custom classmap:

```cs
sealed class AccountBalanceMap : ClassMap<AccountBalance>
{
    public AccountBalanceMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.lastTwelveMonths, false)
            .Name("Jan")
            .ConvertUsing(row => $"{row.lastTwelveMonths[0]}");
        Map(x => x.lastTwelveMonths, false)
            .Name("Feb")
            .ConvertUsing(row => $"{row.lastTwelveMonths[1]}");
        // ...
    }
```

Register the class map with the CsvWriter before using it:

```cs
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<AccountBalanceMap>();
```

You could even construct the class map dynamically using `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName`

```cs
sealed class AccountBalanceMap : ClassMap<AccountBalance>
{
    public AccountBalanceMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            var monthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i + 1);
            var monthIndex = i;
            Map(x => x.lastTwelveMonths, false)
                .Name(monthName)
                .ConvertUsing((row) => $"{row.lastTwelveMonths[monthIndex]}");
        }
    }
}
```